# Facebook friends list as seen by my friend's friend

Tags: facebook, friends

If I have friend  M on Facebook and he has a friend H, does H see that M and I are friends when she looks at my timeline (I have set my friends list to only be shown to me and M's list is public on Facebook)?  I'm only friends with M, not H.

Comment: This is still quite unclear.  What you do mean by M's list is shown on Facebook?  If you are in your friend's list, and H can view his list, wouldn't it follow that she could see you there?

Answer (score 1):

If H looks at M's friends list, they may be able to find you in there. That would usually only be if they are looking for you though.

Also, if H finds their way to your timeline but your friends list is not public, then they won't be able to see your friends. They shouldn't be able to see your mutual (or shared) friends either.